# I want to create events on full calender plugin using qtip2

Tags: fullcalendar, qtip2

I am currently using the http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ (full calender Plugin) and the qtip2 plugin. I want to create events using the qtip2 popover. and i dont have any idea of how to do so? can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the option `select` to a new function `youFunction` (callback). In this new function you should receive the selected date parameters, then you can manipulate and save the event as you wish.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   // put your options and callbacks here
   //...
   select: yourFunction,
   //...
 });

 function yourFunction(startDate, endDate, allDay) {
   //open your popover, manipulate the data and save the event.
 }
```